# THREE js get material context

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I have a `Canvas` map (texture):

```
var mesh;
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context= canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.canvas.width  = context.canvas.height = 128;
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)';
    context.fillText('lala', 64, 85);
var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas); 
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 128, map: texture } );
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();      
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3() );  
mesh = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
scene.add(mesh);
```

**how can I reach context by mesh object reference to update it?**

```
mesh.material.map.image....context?? ... ? what is the correct approach?
```

Comment: Ou that will be ugly and make another problem wit handling and updating this array

Comment: what about context= o.material.map.image.getContext("2d"); ? it works, but is this ok?

Comment: Maybe explain what you are trying to do and why you need the context again.

Comment: to update it in each frame, and to prevent store old context and old  texture in memory

Comment: No use making another question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245038/three-js-best-performance-way-to-update-texture-generated-canvas

Comment: It is the different problem.

Answer (score 1):

works for me:

```
var context = mesh.material.map.image.getContext("2d"); 
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
    //..... draw sprite;
mesh.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
```